# Why are this column's children displaying so differently from each other? Shouldn't they all be displaying the same?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm displaying a column inside a container that's meant to contain a piece of text and a ListView with a number of ToDo items with checkboxes. However, the ListView is not displaying at all. I have no idea why this might be happening.

```
class NotesScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 20.0,
            ),
            height: 70.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xFFFF674F),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
              ),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Note-Taker',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                ),
                ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text('Filler'),
                      trailing: Checkbox(
                        value: false,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, you have embedded the second Column to your first container which has only a height of 70. Probably you want to add it as the second child of your column. Since you are not specifying any size, you have to put that inside an Expanded widget.

```
Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 20.0,
        ),
        height: 70.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xFFFF674F),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Note-Taker',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                fontSize: 20.0,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Filler'),
                    trailing: Checkbox(
                      onChanged: (value) {},
                      value: false,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have you `ListView` inside your second `Column` try this

```
 Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 20.0,
            ),
            height: 70,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xFFFF674F),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
              ),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Note-Taker',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: <Widget>[
                CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text('There would Normally be text here'),
                  value: true,
                  onChanged: (bool value) {},
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Let me know how this works for you